# Skip null using @Insert annotation with Android Room

Tags: java, annotations, sql-insert, android-room

I use a DAO to insert an array of objects (e.g. User[]) into a Room table:

```java
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(User... user);
```

However, it is possible that some objects inside User[] are null. In this case the insertAll() method throws a NullPointerException.

Is it possible to somehow skip null values? I would prefer to use the @Insert annotation instead of writing a custom insert query or filtering out null values beforehand.

Comment: Why you don't want to filter out null values beforehand?

Comment: I'm basically asking if there is something already implemented by Room for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping that Room would have implemented a utility to achieve this, e.g. an annotation like `@Ignore(null)`, but it seems like this isn't the case. This is my solution for now:

Calling the method `ArrayUtils.removeAllOccurences(users, null)` of `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils` and use the result as the argument for `insertAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using default value annotation for the entity fields that can have null value such as: @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")

Also for the entity fields that can have null values place @Nullable annotation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make another array of the same object type
2. Call it temp
3. Iterate through the first array
4. If element[i] is null, exclude it from temp
5. Pass in temp as the argument for your method

Someone on here probably knows some kind of library-defined method of doing what you want to do, but this solution came to my mind first.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that when initializing an array of the same object type, you need to declare the amount of objects it holds beforehand.

Comment: I forgot about that. I'd try a List then.